# Зависает Rails Rspec после Randomized with seed 23785

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Просто внезапно перестал и всё, просто висит, ничего в консоль не выдаёт, нигде в системе ничего не ставил, писал тесты, фабрики и проверял, после чего как уже написал выше в какой-то момент стал в начале странно долго делать, а теперь и вовсе прошло минут 5 ответа никакого - мигающий курсор...

```
macbook-1mac: user$ rspec ./spec/models/task_spec.rb 
Run options: include {:focus=>true}

All examples were filtered out; ignoring {:focus=>true}

Randomized with seed 23785
```

дальше  вечно мигающий курсор дальше ничего

Answer (score 1):

Надеюсь кому-то поможет, причина проста - на сервере зависла именно тестовая база для Rails приложения, после `sudo service mysql restart` работа Rspec восстановилась, ещё и быстро работать стала. Почему зависла база... не знаю.